# Display first name initial in html

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

How can I show show the initial of the first name followed by a period, a space and the last name when working with asp/html/vb?

Comment: how are the names made available to you?

Comment: css and html will not modify the text, you'll need code (VB or JavaScript).  Take a shot at doing it yourself, if you fail, post the code.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for the `Left` function in VBScript.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <%
            Dim FirstName, LastName
            FirstName = "Jeremy"
            LastName = "Wiggins"

            Dim FirstInitial
            FirstInitial = Left(FirstName, 1)
        %>
        <p><%= FirstInitial %>. <%= LastName %></p>
    </body>
</html>
```